# posting in a spring mvc restfull server objects with resource url

Tags: spring-mvc

Im trying to post and object that has a reference to another object, and instead of passing the whole object I just pass the resource uri, how can I do this in spring MVC. I know how to post objects, but dont know how to pass just the reference to the object. :/

here is an example

```
Park: {"director": "/api/v1/user/5/", "place": "/api/v1/place/1/", "name": "End of the work"}
```

How can I manage to post this instead of passing the whole object?

Thanks u soo much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to define a [conversionservice](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert-Spring-config) that looks up the resource and populates the  object.

Comment: Any good tutorial or example to follow, besides the link to spring :).. thanks !!

Comment: I think the spring docs, and the example progs are the best reource - some of the tutorials out there get things wrong